# Plotting a function with complex roots

Tags: plotting

[image]

I want to plot y as a function of x where others are just given known numerical constants. I tried many things didn't work out since I think it also has an imaginary root. How to plot this?

Comment: Please can you give I some values or ranges for the constants? We can then give you examples of how you might plot the roots.

Comment: Try `{g1,wm,capitalD,k,h,wp}=RandomReal[{-1,1},6];
sols=Simplify[y/.Solve[y^3*g1^4/wm^2-2*y^2*g1^2*capitalD/wm+(k^2+capitalD^2)*y== 2*k*x/(h*wp),y]];
Plot[{Re[sols],Im[sols]},{x,-1,1}]` and run that a few times to see the result varies wildly depending on the constants. Then substitute you own constants and see if it works That should show the real parts in one color and the complex parts in a second color. That sometimes gives a warning about not being able to solve with approximate decimals and converting the problem to exact numbers, but that warning may not be a serious problem for you.

Comment: My parameters make the graph disappear. I have given the value of parameters below in the comments. Please suggest possible tweaks.

Answer (score 4):

Adding some bells and whistles to Bill's comment

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[capitalD] := \[ScriptCapitalD];
Format[g1] := Subscript[g, 1];
Format[wm] := Subscript[w, m];
Format[wp] := Subscript[w, p];

label = StringForm["``",
   y^3*g1^4/wm^2 - 2*y^2*g1^2*capitalD/wm + (k^2 + capitalD^2)*y == 
    2*k*x/(h*wp)];

SeedRandom[0]

Manipulate[
 Module[{sols},
  sols = Simplify[
    y /. Solve[
      Rationalize[
       y^3*g1^4/wm^2 - 2*y^2*g1^2*capitalD/wm + (k^2 + capitalD^2)*y == 
        2*k*x/(h*wp), 0], y]];
  Plot[{Re[sols], Im[sols]}, {x, -1, 1},
   PlotLegends -> Placed[
     LineLegend[{Re, Im}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below],
   PlotLabel -> label,
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   MaxRecursion -> 10]],
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({{#, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, -1, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ {capitalD, g1, h, k, wm, wp})],
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

For purely real solutions you can restrict [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to Reals or use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sols, pltRng},
  sols = Simplify[
    y /. Solve[
      Rationalize[
       y^3*g1^4/wm^2 - 2*y^2*g1^2*capitalD/wm + (k^2 + capitalD^2)*y == 
        2*k*x/(h*wp), 0], y, Reals]];
  Column[{
    plt = Plot[sols, {x, -1, 1},
      PlotLabel -> label,
      AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
      PlotPoints -> 50,
      MaxRecursion -> 10,
      ImageSize -> Medium,
      Exclusions -> None],
    pltRng = (PlotRange /. Options[plt, PlotRange])[[2]];
    ContourPlot[
     y^3*g1^4/wm^2 - 2*y^2*g1^2*capitalD/wm + (k^2 + capitalD^2)*y == 
      2*k*x/(h*wp), {x, -1, 1}, {y, pltRng[[1]], pltRng[[2]]},
     PlotLabel -> label,
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
     ImageSize -> Medium,
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]}]],
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({{#, RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, -1, 1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ {capitalD, g1, h, k, wm, wp})],
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Using your newly specified constants

```
Clear["Global`*"]

capitalD = 5*^7 Pi;
g1 = 430 Pi;
h = 105*^-36;
k = 2*^6 Pi;
wm = 2*^7 Pi;
wp = 7757020;

eqn = y^3*g1^4/wm^2 - 2*y^2*g1^2*capitalD/wm + (k^2 + capitalD^2)*y == 
    2*k*x/(h*wp) // Simplify;

sol = Solve[eqn, y];

Plot[Evaluate[ReIm /@ (y /. sol)],
 {x, -1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
 PlotLegends -> Flatten@(ReIm["y" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[Length@sol])]
```

[image]

For the real solution

```
solR = Solve[eqn, y, Reals];

Plot[Evaluate[y /. solR],
 {x, -1, 1},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn,
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -28*^11, 28*^11},
 WorkingPrecision -> 50,
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: The values of my parameters are as follows:$$D=5*\pi*10^7$$ $$g_1=430*\pi $$ $$h=1.05*10^-34$$ $$k=2*\pi*10^6$$ $$w_m=20*\pi*10^6$$  $$w_p=7.75702*10^6$$. I am getting a blank graph at these values , maybe due to scaling.I tried tweaking the code like changing the x scale but to no avail. Can you provide some advice?

Answer (score 3):

Solve `x` by `y` and using `ParametricPlot`

```
 {g1, wm, capitalD, k, h, wp} = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 6];
    Solve[y^3*g1^4/wm^2 - 2*y^2*g1^2*capitalD/wm + (k^2 + capitalD^2)*y ==
        2*k*x/(h*wp), x];
    ParametricPlot[{x, y} /. First@%, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
     AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Comment: You have solved for x in your command. How so?

Comment: Also please provide a source from where I can learn the meaning of the functions you have used such as /.First@%